# How to delete Ubuntu "try it out in parallel" version (20.04) after upgrading the original 18.04 partition (to 20.04)?

Tags: partitioning, upgrade

Good morning.  Question 1230886 (18-04-and-20-04-on-the-same-computer) almost provides the answer, but not quite.

1. The PC (one 120GB disk) is used for Research.  With 18.04, after updates, suddenly fsck was required to be able to boot (nearly every boot).  So instructions were followed to "try out 20.04" then "in parallel" which gave a new partition and added a Grub menu.  There was 80GB (the prior 18.04), something in 500MB and 40GB (with the new 20.04 including swap file/folder).
2. 20.04 ran really well, with Libreoffice Calc, Research evolving only one folder, all work backed up twice a day.  Simple.
3. After six months, selecting Grub> 18.04, still with alarms and fsck,to try to repair things there, it was very unstable; so the advanced option was chosen to do software updates.  However, the automation detected 20.04 elsewhere, can't have two 20.04 installations, so went about replacing the 18.04 with 20.04, successfully completed and then deactivated the 40GB "try it out" partition.  However, it didn't clean it.
4. Now with sda/  (boot), no Grub menu at startup, booting to the original 80GB (20.04 stable) , sda2 at 500MB and sda5 at 40GB, all is well and the full redundant ubuntu system on sda5 can be browsed.  The Research folder (the only user work) is visible at sda5/home..... and backed up anyway.  All the trial ubuntu system there is visible and taking up space.
5. sda5 were best becoming a data library, up to 40GB or joined up again with the sda/ boot (to make room for the Research).  sda5's already nearly full (due to user work, redundant parallel Libreoffice installations (opt) for debug investigations, a redundant Google Earth and so forth yet mostly the redundant Ubuntu trial system).
6. I find instructions for "try out 20.04" in parallel, but not yet how to clean up safely afterward.  I can do partition manipulations (if guided) but am very wary of what Grub used to do, why swap is still on sda5, there are lots of red X marks on folders and if I just format, will I wipe out crucial startup information?  It's preferable to keep the new "permanently chosen" 20.04 (18.04 was equipped with valuable software tools, bookmarks and these have all been successfully inherited).  It's preferable not to format the whole disk and start over, yet I can (have safe and simple backup done already) if absolutely necessary.
7. "Try out 20.04 in parallel" worked automatically very well.  Was there a "Remove the trial version" automatically?  I just didn't see it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you used "Try Ubuntu", nothing was installed.  So there is nothing to remove.

If you installed Ubuntu in more than one location, you can usually delete the partition that contains the installation you no longer want, but this will not add any free space to your other installation.  You would have to resize the partition after you delete the unneeded one.  Make backups because if you make a mistake you will not be able to recover data easily, if at all.

If deleting or resizing partitions is not something you think you will be able to handle and you really want to use all of your hard drive for Ubuntu, reinstall Ubuntu and use the "Erask Disk and Install..." option.

Comment: For other Users, I chose to delete the partition with the 20.04 finished testing (Not "Try", it was indeed an installation in parallel to 18.04).

Comment: For other Users, I chose to delete the partition with the 20.04 finished testing (Not "Try", it was indeed an installation in parallel to 18.04).   With GParted I deleted sda5, then deleted it's host sda3.  Apply.  Then sda2 (half Giga and apparently empty) was in the middle, preventing resizing the actual boot sda1.  So I move sda2 to the end (by setting "space after" to zero, still 500MB only in size).  Apply.  sda1 boot was ready for resizing.  I set maximum (again by "space after" to zero).  Apply.   I thought it wise to reboot after each change.   Two minutes, no formatting.  Thankyou.